# Is there a way to pick the first element in hashtable keys?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

Is there a way to pick the first element in hashtable keys?

```
$stringData=@'
DEV=True
UAT=False
'@
$oTest=ConvertFrom-StringData $stringData
$oTest.Keys
$oTest.Values
```

Looking for

```
DEV
```

Comment: I think hashtable in Powershell does not remember it's order.

Answer (score 0):

As currently written, `$oTest.GetType().FullName` returns `System.Collections.Hashtable`. 
Try rather [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary) (represents a collection of key/value pairs that are accessible by the key or index.)

```
$stringData=@'
DEV=True
UAT=False
'@
$oTest2 = [ordered]@{}
$stringData -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    ForEach-Object {
        $aux = ConvertFrom-StringData $_
        $oTest2.Add("$($aux.Keys)","$($aux.Values)")
    }
$oTestKey0 = ($oTest2.Keys -as [array])[0]
$oTestKey0, $oTest2.$oTestKey0 -join ','
# or
([array]$oTest2.Keys)[0], $oTest2[0] -join ';'
```

**Result**: PS D:\PShell> `D:\PShell\SO\75900961.ps1`

> ```
> DEV,True
> DEV;True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) cmdlet only returns an unordered Hashtable.
You could create your own function like that cmdlet to give you more options about the object that is returned.

Something like this:

```
function ConvertFrom-StringData2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$StringData,

        [char]$Delimiter = '=',    # default to equal sign

        [ValidateSet('Hashtable', 'OrderedHash', 'PsCustomObject')]
        [string]$As = 'Hashtable'  # default to unordered Hashtable
    )
    # prepare the object to output
    if ($As -eq 'Hashtable') { 
        $objOut = @{} 
    } 
    elseif ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 3) {
        $objOut = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
    }
    else {
        $objOut = [ordered]@{} 
    }

    # split the multiline string into an array of lines, omit empty or whitespace-only lines
    $StringData -split '\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
        # use string .Split() method instead of regex -split 
        # to avoid having to escape the delimiter character
        $name, $value = $_.Split($Delimiter, 2).Trim('" ')
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($name)) { $objOut[$name] = $value }
    }

    if ($As -eq 'PsCustomObject') {
        if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 3) {
            return New-Object PSObject -Property $objOut  
        }
        return [PsCustomObject]$objOut
    }
    $objOut
}
```

In your example case you can now do

```
$stringData=@'
DEV=True
UAT=False
'@

$stringData | ConvertFrom-StringData2 -As OrderedHash
```

or to get only the first item

```
($stringData | ConvertFrom-StringData2 -As OrderedHash).GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -First 1
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                       
DEV                            True
```